# Change font size of an align environment

Tags: equations, align, fontsize

In a document, I'd like to change the font size of a **single** align environment (not globally throughout the document).  What is the proper way to do this?  I've been using

```
Preceding paragraph.
{\tiny
    \begin{align}
        a &< b
    \end{align}
}
Following paragraph.
```

But this seems to cause some weird artifacts (e.g., an unwanted indentation at the beginning of the following paragraph).

Comment: I do not see any artifacts in your example.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Insert a `%` symbol after closing the group with `\tiny`:

```
{\tiny
}%
Following paragraph.
```

Otherwise the line break in the source is treated like a space, which causes that small indentation of the following paragraph.

Furthermore, consider adjusting the spacing around that align environment. The spacing before and after a displayed math environment with smaller font could be made smaller than a normal one. Such changes have only local effect because of the grouping by braces.

For example:

```
Preceding paragraph.
{\tiny  
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{6pt}
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{3pt}
  \begin{align}
      a &< b
  \end{align}
}%
Following paragraph.
```

Comment: one artifact not mentioned is that if the preceding paragraph has more than one line, the baselines of that paragraph will be the same as those for the "smallified" display, that is, too tight.  the simplest cure for this problem is to leave a blank line or insert a `\par` before the grouped display.  since it's bad form to allow a page break just before a display, `\par\nobreak` is an even better idea.  vertical spacing between the paragraph and the display may be affected, but can be corrected by judicious use of `\vspace{...}`.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed this later and was about to ask this follow-up question!

Comment: A solution to the issue @barbarabeeton points out is nicely packaged up into a new environment in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/612073/19048