# How to resize font in align* environment

Tags: equations, align, fontsize

A similar question has been posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33585/change-font-size-of-an-align-environment) about the `align` environment. However, the solution does not seem to work for `align*`.

```
Preceding paragraph.
{\small
    \begin{align*}
        a &< b
    \end{align*}
}%
Following paragraph.
```

Comment: I cannot see the difference between the sizes of the two versions.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm trying to see how I can make `a &< b` appear smaller.

Comment: what was your actual question? You have accepted an answer that just points out that `align` and `align*` work the same way, so there is no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we have no minimal example, an example when it works. (If you have some special combination of packages, please show the minimal example, when it doesn't work for you.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}


Preceding paragraph.
{\small
    \begin{align}
        a &< b
    \end{align}
}
Following paragraph.


Preceding paragraph.
{\small
    \begin{align*}
        a &< b
    \end{align*}
}
Following paragraph.

\end{document}
```

(When we replace `\small` by, say, `\tiny`, the result is awful, but the same sizes are easy visible.)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but this ***never*** works. Consider this example, where `\scriptsize` is used to make the effect more apparent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\lipsum[1][1-4]
{\scriptsize\begin{align*}
a&<b \\
c&<d
\end{align*}}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\small` instead of `\scriptsize` the bad typesetting is still present, albeit less evident:

[image]

Here's a way to make it work without bad effects. Again, `\scriptsize` is used to better illustrate that the result is as wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newenvironment{sizeddisplay}[1]
 {\par\nopagebreak#1\noindent\ignorespaces}
 {\nopagebreak\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{sizeddisplay}{\scriptsize}
\begin{align*}
a&<b \\
c&<d
\end{align*}
\end{sizeddisplay}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was looking for.  I assumed I could just wrap the align environment in a simple `{\small ... }`, but the pernicious  spacing badness it causes in the preceding paragraph is a sad side-effect since it might go unnoticed.  Thanks for this.